# Unable to get pagebreak for References unless Figures move to bottom

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, endfloat

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\graphicspath{ {C:Users/} }
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\doublespacing


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 


\newpage
\setcounter{page}{6}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{Introduction}
sfdfgf

\subsection{fsfsfs}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.7\textwidth]{pic1}
   \caption{fsgfsg}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.8\textwidth]{pic2}
   \caption{fsgfsgsf}
\end{figure}

sfgsfdg \cite{ref1}

\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

I tried to display my minimum working example above, but its not quite representative of my actual latex. If I don't include `\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}`, then the References section starts on page 30, but the Table of Contents says the References section begins on page 28. If I then include `\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}`, then the Table of Contents' page number for References matches the actual page number for References. However, all the Figures then appear at the bottom of the pdf after the References

How do I fix this?

Comment: if you use endfloat then naturally the floats go to the end, for the page numbers don't they come right if you latex the document two or three times? impossible to the your exampe as we don't have the files.

Comment: Using `[h]` (or `[h!]` makes it hard for latex to position the figures and usually generates a warning that it is being changed to `[ht]` but better to use `[htp]` if you want to allow `h`